# How to remove all characters between "<" and ">" including "<" and ">"?

Tags: c#, .net, string

I have string:

```
window.google.ac.h(["hãy nghe lời ô",[["hãy nghe lời <b><i>cô<\/i><\/b>",30,[10,40]]],{"j":"13","o":"hãy nghe lời <sc>cô<\/sc>","p":"hãy nghe lời <se>ô<\/se>","q":"a3-RB5VEFG4py23rfvkQ1MtM5Vk"}])
```

but I want string:

```
window.google.ac.h(["hãy nghe lời ô",[["hãy nghe lời cô",30,[10,40]]],{"j":"13","o":"hãy nghe lời cô","p":"hãy nghe lời ô","q":"a3-RB5VEFG4py23rfvkQ1MtM5Vk"}])
```

All substring like `<b>`, `<\/b>` should be removed.

Is any way to do this by C#?

Comment: Have you looked into [regular expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx)? Otherwise, if, and only if this happens to be well-formed Xml (after adding the tags for a root element), you could try Xml-aware approaches (XSLT or one of C#'s Xml APIs), too.

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: Try to provide latin language symbols only when posting into the `.com` sites.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use regular expression to remove tags:

```
result = Regex.Replace(source, "<.*?>", string.Empty);
```