# How to get all characters betwent "[\"" and "\","?

Tags: c#, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove all characters between “<” and “>” including “<” and “>”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12337243/how-to-remove-all-characters-between-and-including-and)
>   [How to fix this error when I try to get all substring between [“ and ”, (have code)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12347475/how-to-fix-this-error-when-i-try-to-get-all-substring-between-and-have-co)

I have string:

```
window.google.ac.h(["new yor",[["new york times",0,[]],["new york",0,[]],["new york city",0,[]],["new york university",0,[]],["new york school",0,[]]],{"j":"13","q":"ggIoEiJIv-q5I7KyDDspEWBWyH0"}])
```

I want these strings:

```
new yor
new york times
new york city
new york university
new york school
```

All these strings are betwent `["` and `",`

Is any way to do this?

Comment: Instead of posting [very similar questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12337243/how-to-remove-all-characters-between-and-including-and), you should really consider researching the general topic yourself. In this case, that's regular expressions.

Comment: @ codesparkle: no, that post is remove, but this is get these strings

Comment: @TuyenTk you didn't understand: this is not a **do my work for me** site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your task can be effectivelly accomplished using regular expressions. Your regex could look like:

```
(?<=\[")[^"]+
```

See it live [here](http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=9d916435-330d-4e1c-8baa-10eb784b16f4).

The `(?<=\[")` part is so called lookbehind, you say you are looking for anything that follows `["`.
Then you simply take any characters except `"`

Extract from [.NET Regex Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc):

> **(?<= subexpression)** Zero-width positive lookbehind assertion.
>
> **[^ character_group ]** Negation: Matches any single character that is
>   not in character_group. By default, characters in character_group are
>   case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the .IndexOf("[\"") extension on the string that returns an int of the index of this item, then do the same for the other string.

Once you have a int of both indexes, you can .SubString it based on those indexes.