# How to fix this error when I try to get all substring between [" and ", (have code)?

Tags: c#, regex, substring

I have string:

```
new y",[["new york",0,[]],["new york times",0,[]
```

I want these string betwent `["` and `",`:

```
new york
new york times
```

I tried this function:

```
public MatchCollection s;
...
s =  Regex.Matches(s44, "[\".*?\",");
```

but I got this error: `ArgumentException was unhandled: prasing "[".*?"," - Unterminated [] set`.

Can you help me solve this problem? Thank you very much!

**Edit:** The string I want dont have `["` and `",`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to escape the bracket. Additionally, you need to introduce a group by using the parenthesis. The text you want is than contained in that group:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(s44, "\\[\"(.*?)\",");
foreach(Match match in matches)
{
    var result = match.Groups[1].Value;
}
```

Comment: Thank for help. The string I want dont have [" and ",. Can you help me more a bit?

Answer (score 2):

I have already answered this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12337540/944681) yesterday, use `Regex.Matches(@"(?<=\["")[^""]+")`

Using the @ prefix, you make the string literal, which means in your case the backlashes are handled as other characters and you don't need to escape them. But you need to double the double quotes.

The lookbehind part was already explained, so please don't repost the same question next time.

Comment: but when I use, I got above error. Thank for answer my question.

Comment: have you added the @ sign? i don't think so

Comment: @MichalKlouda: you forgot to escape the double quotes.

Comment: @TuyenTk: If an answer doesn't work you have to post a comment to that answer. You are NOT allowed to post the same question a second time!

Comment: @DanielHilgarth thanks, i have noticed a bit later. You are right, and you have my +1 ;)

Comment: @MichalKlouda: I am trying to understand why you are using a look behind. I don't think that it is necessary, can you elaborate?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth It's definitelly not necessary, you either use groups or lookbehind, the same power I would say. I used it yesterday because it was easier to setup live [demo](http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=9d916435-330d-4e1c-8baa-10eb784b16f4) ;)

Comment: @Michal Klouda: Thank, I forgot the @ sign, I'm a newbie so I dont know it is important. Because i think that is bother you when I comment that question. And I hove you sympathetic for me, I'm a newbie, both in C# and StackOverflow, I'm a student, I dont learn about coding but I like it. thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want:

```
Regex.Matches(s44, "(?<=\\[\").*?(?=\",)");
```

output: `new york, new york times`

**[Regex Demo](http://regexr.com?323k1)**